# Input value depends on value of dropdown from database

Tags: php, mysql

How to echo the value of dropdown select in textbox?

What I need is when house is selected the value ACR100 should echo in the empty textbox. Display the value in textbox depends on the value of dropdown.

How to do that?

```
id  |  maincode | category  
1   |  ACR100   |  House
2   |  ACR200   |  Park  
3   |  ACR300   |  Field
```

Php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $resultcode = $mysqli->query("SELECT category, id, maincode FROM category GROUP BY id ORDER BY maincode");
    $code = '';
     while($row = $resultcode->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $code .= '<option value = "'.$row['maincode'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
?>

<select name="supplier" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<?php echo $code; ?>
</select>

<input name="catvalue" value="">
```

Comment: As far as I understand you're requirement, you'll achieve this best using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to happen on the client side you could do it easily with jquery. 
http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$('[name="supplier"]').change(function() {
   $('[name="catvalue"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

I haven't run the code but you get the idea.

**EDIT:**

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dn7Y/) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to achieve that. You just have to attach an event to your options menu and your document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<!-- call function to set value when document loads -->
<body onload="initialize()">     
<!-- attach an onchange event to update input field -->
<select id="dropdownList" onchange="update()">
<option value="ACR100">House</option>
<option value="ACR110">Park</option>
<option value="ACR120">Field</option>

    </select>
    <input id="catvalue" name="catvalue" value="">

    <script>
        // update input field
        function update(){
            var value = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
            var dest = document.getElementById("catvalue");

            dest.value = value;                
        }

        //run when document loads
        function initialize(){
            update();
        }           
    </script>
</body>
```

Alternatively, instead of attaching the initialize function to your whole document, you can just set the value in php while printing the page, like Anonymous did.